# rewrite displayed url without actual redirect

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to change displayed urls to keep all sub domain urls relative to the main domain, example **maindomain.com/some_page** would be served from **sub.maindomain.com/some_page** but to keep the displayed url in browser to **maindomain.com/some_page**.
Considering that the main domain and the sub are hosted on different servers as explained hereunder:

1. maindomain.com, is wordpress powered by LEMP server with following nginx.conf:

   ```
   server {
   listen 80;
   server_name maindomain.com;
   root /var/www/html;
   index index.php index.html index.htm;
   include /var/www/html/nginx.conf;
   client_max_body_size 65M;

   error_page 404 @sub;

   location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
   }

   location /xmlrpc.php {
           deny all;
   }

   location = /xmlrpc.php {
           deny all;
           access_log off;
           log_not_found off;
           return 444;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
           include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
   }

   location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|htc|bmp|ico|rtf|png|xml|otf|ttf|eot|woff|mid|midi|woff2|svg|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2)$ {
           expires max;
           log_not_found off;
   }

   # redirect all not found pages to the sub domain
   location @sub {
           rewrite ^ http://sub.maindomain.com$request_uri redirect;
   }
   }
   ```
2. sub.maindomain.com, is Node.js app with nginx as proxy server.

   ```
   upstream app {
     server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=120;
   }

   server {
     listen 80;
     server_name sub.maindomain.com;
     root /var/webapp;
     # Compression
     gzip on;
     gzip_types text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;
     gzip_buffers 16 8k;
     gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
     # Error pages
     error_page 404 /404.html;
     location /404.html { root /app/public; }
     error_page 500 /500.html;
     location /500.html { root /app/public; }
     # Client configuration
     client_max_body_size 4G;
     keepalive_timeout 120;

     # Logs
     access_log no;

     # Serve static assets
     location ^~ /assets/ {
       gzip_static on;
       expires max;
       add_header Cache-Control public;
     }

     # Try physical files first then proxy to running application
     try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
     location @app {
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
       proxy_redirect off;
       rewrite ^/(.*) http://maindomain.com$1 break;
       proxy_pass http://app;
     }
   }
   ```

I've tried different variations of rewriting rules but nothing doing the trick.

Comment: Just proxy pass to the upstream. `rewrite` will, as the name suggests, rewrite the url

Comment: @miknik you mean i don't need this line rewrite ^/(.*) http://maindomain.com$1 break; and only proxy pass to upstream but in this case the ned result will be redirecting from maindomain to the sub and the url will be sub.maindomain.com

Comment: Rewrite is usually used to perform `internal` redirection - meaning `inside` nginX (so the client is `usually` not aware of the rewrite - unless you rewrite to something which starts with `http://` or `https://`), while `return 301` is used when you want to make the client aware of the redirection. In your case you can not do what you want directly - you will have to use either AJAX or frames/iframes, otherwise the real URL will be exposed in the address bar.